Can I rewire a water heater to require smaller breakers?
I have a tankless electric water heater that has 4 double pole 40 amp breakers. I am purchasing a new water heater that needs two 60 amp breakers. Can I rewire to use the 40 amp breakers?

Almost definitely not. And that's not the only problem...
In most situations, wiring is only as much as needed. For a 40A circuit (of which you have 4 right now), that is most likely 8 AWG wire or cable, copper (most likely) or aluminum. There is no common reason to upsize, particularly in a situation such as this one where 4 circuits had to be run at one time. With a single circuit it is a little more common, though still unusual. Some uncommon reasons are:

Don't have the right size wire on the truck but have larger wire. This is common for substituting 12 AWG for 14 AWG on a 15A circuit. Less common with larger sizes.
Planning for the future. Common with a subpanel installation or EVSE (car charging) because you might not have only enough capacity for 40A now but with a service upgrade have more capacity in the future. But unlikely here as (a) that is commonly with one circuit, not 4 and (b) 160A (40A x 4) of water heating already likely required a service upgrade, considering that a common 200A service would almost certainly not have enough capacity for 160A of water heating.

So you almost certainly have 4 x 8 AWG circuits and you now need 2 larger circuits. Those could be:

4 AWG copper cable
6 AWG copper wires in conduit
4 AWG aluminum wires in conduit, provided your water heater allows aluminum wiring

But running new cables/wires is usually not that big a deal, at least if the water heater is fairly close to the panel.
But you have a much bigger problem: water heater capacity
Tankless electric resistance water heating capacity is directly related to the amount of available power. 4 x 40A x 240V = 38.4 kW. 2 x 60A x 240V = 28.8 kW. That's 75% of the capacity. If your old water heater produced "just enough for maximum usage" then you are going to find the new one will not produce enough hot water for your needs. Even worse, if you were sold the new one based on "existing system does not have enough capacity" + "60A circuits are better than 40A circuits" (which they are - 50% larger) you are going to be sorely disappointed by the much worse performance of the new system.
Almost definitely, each of the 4 circuits in the old system fed one big toaster element, with 1 circuit also providing power for the controls (minimal). The new system has 2 circuits each feeding one even bigger toaster element, with 1 circuit also providing power for the controls. Besides violating manufacturer instructions and code, if you:

Connect each new 60A heater element to a single 40A set of wires and don't change the breaker: Breakers will trip frequently, unless they fail catastrophically.
Connect each new 60A heater element to a single 40A set of wires and change the breaker to 60A: Wires will overload and very possibly lead to melting and even a fire.
Connect each new 60A heater element to a pair of 40A wires/breakers: This is paralleling and is not allowed under most residential situations. If everything works perfectly (load always exactly split) then you risk problems if the heater has a defect (because then you will be effectively using 80A circuits for 60A-rated equipment). If there is any problem in the wiring (one loose wire out of the 4 hot wires) then you will end up with breaker trip and/or wires overloading and very possibly lead to melting and even a fire.

So before doing anything, determine if this new 120A water heater will actually satisfy your needs. Maybe it will - e.g., 160A was more than you actually needed - in which case, rewire two circuits correctly and you will be OK.
But if this won't satisfy your needs, don't make the change.
And if your real reason is:

Need to add 40A of EVSE (car charging)
No excess capacity, so dropping the water heater from 160A to 120A will give me 40A to spare

then:

Consider that EVSE can often do just fine with 30A or even just 20A, so you may have enough capacity if you lower your EVSE requirements
Automatic load shedding is ideal for this. EV charging generally takes several hours. A few minutes of "dial down the EVSE automatically because the water heater is running at full capacity" won't affect your charge time in a significant way, as long as it is all done automatically.


Can you address the possibility of "Connect each new 60A heater element to a pair of 40A wires, which join back to a single 60A breaker"?  Pretty sure that's forbidden by code, because what happens if the one of the wires becomes open circuit -- the entire 60A would flow in the other wire -- but best to explain why it's a bad idea.

I agree with that question @BenVoigt -- that was my first thought and it took a second of consideration to land on the what if one wire fails/disconnected possibility.  Pretty easy for a weekend warrior to stumble on your idea and fail to consider the ramification.

Only if the instructions for the heater say that you can do so. USA's NEC code requires following the device's instructions exactly. I'd guess most other countries' codes are similar. Your fire department and insurance company will have things to say and do if you don't follow the instructions and they have to express opinion about your installation.
If the heater's instructions do not say "Here is how to re-wire the heater for 40 amp breakers..." then you must either return the heater for one that uses 40 amp breakers, or must re-wire the exiting circuits to use 60-amp-capable wires and breakers. There is no safe & code compliant way to finagle the existing 40 amp circuits to become 60 amp circuits.

And yes, there are heaters with instructions for this.  My (tanked) water heater can be converted between 3800 W and 5500 W, with different breaker and wiring requirements for each mode (12 gauge/20 amp at 3300 W, 10 gauge/30 amp at 5500 W).
